# Pull to Refresh UWP - Grid view?

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, pull-to-refresh

Could someone please advise me on the "correct" way of implementing Pull to refresh on UWP?

---

Below are some examples I've found however I'm not sure which one is using the best approach:

- [Microsoft sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPullToRefresh) which is for a ListView - This works however it is specific to the ListView Control
- [AmazingPullToRefresh](https://github.com/tmyt/AmazingPullToRefresh) is a NuGet package that also works however it is somewhat limited in terms of styling
- [PullToRefreshUWP_WindowsComposition](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/PullToRefreshUWP_WindowsComposition) is another example however it works differently to the other two as it does not use an extension class

Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard answer for this question, basically, there are two points we need to implement:

1. Get the offset changes when user pull something on the control
2. Generate some indicator to notify user

---

Both [XamlPullToRefresh](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPullToRefresh) and [PullToRefreshUWP_WindowsComposition](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/PullToRefreshUWP_WindowsComposition) use the new Windows Composition API: [Windows.UI.Composition namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.composition.aspx)

Ref [Windows.UI.Composition Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/graphics/visual-layer)

> The API is a powerful supplement to existing frameworks such as XAML
>   to give developers of UWP applications a familiar C# surface to add to
>   their application. These APIs can also be used to create DX style
>   framework-less applications.

**Please notice that this API works only on Windows 10.**

---

**While** [AmazingPullToRefresh](https://github.com/tmyt/AmazingPullToRefresh) uses Manipulation API and implement all things by calculating offset changes. A similar implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/zmtzawqlp/UWP-master/tree/1fafaa459d008cc02a5577ec8fe24d0508afc49c/src/MyUWPToolkit/MyUWPToolkit/Panel/PullToRefresh)

---

If you want to implement a cool pull-to-refresh control, I would recommend using the `Windows.UI.Composition` API. You can get start from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs)

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of pulling to refresh is not used by microsoft.

Reloading a page / data is something we have still in our mind from thinking apps like a website.

Why not have a synced database and alway update your UI with the data which got changed in your local db? For eg. see [firebase.google.com](http://firebase.google.com/)

If you want to implement this feature anyway there is not really a way to go.
I have used the PullToRefresh.UWP library from NuGet. For a tutorial see:
[codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1044631/Pull-to-refresh-on-a-Windows-UWP)

With some tweaking it works but sometimes when I lift my finger of the screen after pulling down the bar won't go up again.

So the answer is: Sorry, but nobody can give you an answer on how to do this the "correct" way. But is there a correct way anywhere? Like almost always in programming. It depends on the case you will use it.
Hope this will help you.